# IIS7 default pool is running under which account

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I need to give this account some write permisison. Is the account Network_User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default user is `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` but it's hidden by default so you won't see it in the security UI.  You can still add permissions for this user though, you just can't search for it.

You can also do it programmatically:

```
icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account